# Getting an error while using Object.defineProperty() method to add getters and setters to an already existing object

Tags: javascript, object, getter, setter

Error: Uncaught TypeError property description must be an object : h

Getting an above error while using Object.defineProperty() method to add setters and getters to an already existing object to modify values of property in a object.

```
const jump = {
height: "10:00mtr",
time: "10seconds",
    
}

//adding a setters and getters to height.
Object.defineProperties(jump, "height2", {
        get: function () {
            return this.height;
        },
        set: function (newHeight) {
            return this.height = newHeight;
    },
});

//adding a setters and getters to time.
Object.defineProperties(jump, "time2", {
    get: function () {
        return this.time;
    },
    set: function (newTime) {
        return this.time = newTime;
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This particular syntax you use is reserved to `Object.defineProperty` rather than `Object.defineProperties`. Your only mistake is then using `Object.defineProperties` where you was supposed to use `Object.defineProperty`.

Even in your question title you ask about `Object.defineProperty` but still you use `Object.defineProperties` in the code below.

Corrected code:

```
Object.defineProperty(jump, "height2", {
    get: function () {
        return this.height;
    },
    set: function (newHeight) {
        return this.height = newHeight;
    },
});
```

On the other hand, `Object.defineProperties` is used to define multiple propeties at once and should be used like this:

```
Object.defineProperties(jump, 
  {
    "height2": 
    {
      get: function () {
          return this.height;
      },
      set: function (newHeight) {
          return this.height = newHeight;
      }
    },
    "anotherProperty: 
    {
      ...
    }
  });
```